# Сортировка первого массива относительно второго PHP

Tags: php

Первый массив

```
$first = array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Второй массив

```
$second = array(8,2,5,7)
```

Необходимо отсортировать первый массив таким образом, чтобы в начале шли элементы из второго массива в том же порядке. Желаемый результат:

```
$first = array(2,5,1,3,4,6)
```

**Важный момент:** массивы разной длины и в первом массиве может не быть элементов из второго. После сортировки порядок элементов, которых нет во втором массиве, не важен.

Мой вариант ниже, но не сохраняется порядок элементов.

```
usort($first, function ($a, $b) use ($second) {
    return in_array($a, $second) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

то есть я получаю что-то вроде

```
$first = array(5,2,1,3,4,6)
```

Comment: не мудрите с сортировкой, возьмите пересечение массивов, и с ним делайте что надо. потом остатки добавьте, как надо.

Comment: Если первый массив 1,5,3,6,2,4, то результат будет 2,5,1, 3, 4 ,5, 6?

Comment: @becouse результатом будет 2,5,(1,3,6,4) - порядок элементов в скобках не имеет значения

Comment: Тогда не верная постановка задачи. Тут нет сортировки. Нужно переместить в начало одного массива пересечение двух массивов. Правильно?

Comment: @becouse можно и так сформулировать. Но по сути мы же сортируем элементы в первом массиве по определенному алгоритму без изменения набора элементов в самом массиве.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример решения вашей задачи

```
$first = array_merge(array_intersect($second, $first),array_diff($first,$second));
```

Сортировка предполагает, что для всех элементов отсортированого массива порядковая функция возвращает одинаковое значение. Например сортировка по возрастанию: $a[i]<=$a[i+1].

В вашем случае речь идет о перестановке элементов.

Comment: Протестировал, работает как нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот не очень эффективное, но простое решение

```
$first = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$second = array(8,2,5,7);

$part1 = array();
$part2 = array();

foreach ($second as $el) {
    if (in_array($el, $first)) {
         $part1[] = $el;
    }
}

foreach ($first as $el) {
    if (!in_array($el, $second)) {
        $part2[] = $el;
    }
}

$result = array_merge($part1, $part2);
```